# Extract content from Wikipedia to Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions, semantic-mediawiki

Is there a way to get the intro content from wikipedia page to my mediawiki page? I was thinking of using wikipedia's api but i dont know how to parse the url on my page and also with templates. I just want a query that will display the introduction part of a wikipedia page on my page?d

Comment: Can you describe what you tried and how it didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I used the [External_Data Extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:External_Data)  and Wikipedia's api to achieve this.

The API

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php? action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=[title of wikipedia page]
```

How I used it

```
{{#get_web_data:
url=http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php? action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles={{PAGENAME}}
|format=JSON|data=extract=extract}}
```

How I displayed the extract on pages

```
{{#external_value:extract}}
```

I however need to figure out how to get only a paragraph from the return text. Will probably use a parser function.